# using while loop in python to find volume and surface area of a cone but getting incorrect answers except the first radius entered

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to find the volume and surface area of a cone using the radius from 10-20 with a step of .5 and print the results. I get the correct response when using 10 but all the following responses are wrong. What am I missing?

Here's what I've got:

```
pi = 3.14159265359
radius = 10
height = radius * 2
import math

print ('{0: <10}'.format('radius'),\
'{0: <10}'.format('area'),\
'{0: <10}'.format('volume'))

while radius >= 9.5 and radius <= 20:
    area = pi * radius * (radius + math.sqrt(height**2 + radius**2))
    volume = pi * radius**2 * height / 3
    print(format(radius, '<10,.2f'), \
    format(area, '<10,.2f'), \
    format(volume, '<12,.2f'))
    radius = radius + .5
```

Comment: you don't appear to redefine height for each new value of radius

Comment: yes you're right. i redefined and am now getting the correct answers all the way through. i was hoping it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `height = radius * 2` after the last line. Remember about the indentation.